# Deploy Angular 10 app with localize using Firebase

Tags: angular, localization, angular-i18n

I'm using Angular 10 (the last version at the moment) and `@angular/localize` to translate my app into french and english.

Everything is well configured.

For the build, I'm using this command:

```
"build:prod": "ng build --prod --localize"
```

which gives:

[image]

I want to deploy the app using Firebase. I correctly set everything when running `firebase init hosting`

`firebase.json` looks like:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/myAngularApp",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now my issue is that there is no `index.html` file at the root of `dist/myAngularApp` so when deploying and targeting default url, nothing is displayed.

For example:

- on the browser I target `https://XXXXXXX.web.app/en/` -> English version rendered: OK
- on the browser I target `https://XXXXXXX.web.app/fr/` -> French version rendered: OK
- on the browser I target `https://XXXXXXX.web.app/` -> Nothing and I wish it redirects to '/en/' relative path

I want to render the english version of the app by default and I expected, I could specify it when building my project using a specific option or inside `angular.json` file.

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: did you try to add a rewrite rule to your hosting object: `"rewrites": [ { "source": "**", "destination": "/en/index.html"} ]`

Comment: Looks like it did the trick

Comment: Glad i could help, I placed it as an answer for future readers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a rewrite rule to your hosting object in your `firebase.json`:

```
"rewrites": [ 
  { "source": "**", "destination": "/en/index.html"} 
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Now you can set up i18n rewrites. Please add this:

```
//firebase.json

"i18n": {
    "root": "localized-files" //directory that contains your i18n folders
 }
```

Firebase serves content based on the values of the "Accept-Language" header

Complete reference at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/i18n-rewrites